# Can I replace my laptop's old 1TB hard regular hard drive with a 1TB SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sata

I have a great Asus G751J laptop that is a few years old. So I am starting to get hard drive errors and bad sectors, etc., and I need to replace the 1TB regular hard drive. I checked with Asus support and they said that I could only replace the 1TB Sata hard drive with a 256 GB SSD Sata 3 hard drive. That seems little odd, since why should the disk volume matter as long as the disk form factor fits in my laptop.

Hence, I was just hoping someone could confirm that I can fit a 1 TB SSD in the computer instead of a 1TB Sata drive? Or should I follow what the Asus person said and just replace with another 1 TB Sata drive like the original?

Comment: It’s a bit of a cheat, but I commonly outsource this sort of question to Crucial (dot com). They have done most of the hard work in terms of making it easy to determine compatible hard drives (and RAM). From there you can find a suitable drive on or off the site.

Comment: https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/g751jy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main considerations, but you can easily verify by accessing your existing drive to confirm, if the information isn't in the manual:

1. **Physical Interface**: There are 4 applicable SATA connector form factors, they follow the drive's physical size. The most common drive size and interface for a notebook HDD is 2.5". 1.8" drives are less common and use either mSATA (mini SATA) or uSATA (micro SATA) connectors. There are also M.2 SATA SSDs.
2. **Drive Height**: In addition to the physical interface, the drive's height plays a role in compatibility. A drive that is too tall may not fit in your system. A drive that is too short may strain the connector if the drive is able to move after installation. A rubber pad, drop of hot glue, or tape may be sufficient to immobilize the drive.

So long as your replacement disk follows the above fitment concerns, there's virtually no limit to capacity of your replacement disk.

Comment: thanks for the advice and for being so comprehensive. I think I know what to do now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to replace with a 1TB (or larger) drive in a SATA carrier. It may be that ASUS does not carry larger SSD drives.

### Caveats:

1. Have a solid backup.
2. You need to clone, not copy, the drive and as part of the cloning process you should be able to change the sizing.

*DISCLOSURE: I have cloned system drives to different size SSD drives, but not on an ASUS.*

Comment: Thanks @Charles Kenyon. That definitely gives me more confidence. I basically run everything off of dropbox, so everything is already backed up. Now I can try swapping out the drive. Thanks again for your help.